# Max Points on a Line Compile Error

Tags: python, compiler-errors

Below is my python code to the oj problem: "Max Points on a Line", I test it locally with lots test points and it seems ok, but the oj reply "Compile Error".

Is there anything wrong I missed?

```
import operator

class Solution:
    # @param points, a list of Points
    # @return an integer
    def maxPoints(self, points):
        pointset = set(points)
        if len(pointset) < 3:
            return len(points)
        else:
            pointdict ={pkey:points.count(pkey) for pkey in pointset}
            count = 0

            while len(pointset) > 1:
                point1 = pointset.pop()
                point2set = pointset.copy()

                while point2set:
                    point2 = point2set.pop()
                    point3set = point2set.copy()

                    lineset = {point1, point2}

                    if point3set:
                        for point3 in point3set:
                            if (point1.x-point2.x)*(point2.y-point3.y) == (point2.x-point3.x)*(point1.y-point2.y) :
                                lineset.add(point3)
                                point2set.remove(point3)

                    linecount = reduce(operator.add, [pointdict[p] for p in lineset])

                    if linecount > count: 
                        count = linecount
            return count
```

Comment: That does appear to be valid Python 3, but it is not valid Python 2. Are you sure you’ve indicated to whatever service you’re submitting this to that it is Python 3?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And I test it in Python 2.7.8, it's ok.

Comment: Oh, right. Python 2.7 backported some Python 3 features. Perhaps wherever you’re submitting it is still running 2.6 or some older version.

Comment: But the site I submit the code is running Python 2.7.5 [https://oj.leetcode.com/faq/](https://oj.leetcode.com/faq/)

Comment: IMHO it's a bit weird that they want the solution as a class, but I guess that's to make it uniform across languages. But since you _are_ doing this as a class I suggest that you pass the list of test points in the constructor, i.e. as the parameter of the class's `__init__()` method. Of course if you do that you should change `maxPoints()` so that its only arg is `self`.